# Sending push notifications when published product

Tags: node.js

It is necessary to send a push-notification to all users on the phones (iOS to Android), that a new product has been added to the store.

How can this be realized? I would like to see an example

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pushnotifications also you need to setup firebase https://www.androidauthority.com/android-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-925075/

Comment: Will it work with ios and with android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be tempted to look at a complete solution:
https://github.com/appfeel/node-pushnotifications

This works with both Android and iOS.

Without repeating what the documentation already states, this should do what you're looking for.